# Rate at which planet "sweeps out area"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, vector-analysis, mathematical-astronomy

I want to show that the rate at which a planet circling around a star in an orbit is "sweeps out area" is $\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}r^2\omega$, where $r$ is the distance from the star to the planet and $\omega$ is the planet's angular velocity ($\dot{\phi}$ in polar coordinates).

It can be seen that the infinitesimal "wedge" area is $dA=\lVert d\vec{A}\rVert=\frac{1}{2}\left\rVert\vec{r}\times(\vec{r}+d\vec{r})\right\rVert = \frac{1}{2}rdr\sin(d\phi)\approx \frac{1}{2}d\phi rdr$ (since $d\phi$ is small).
Dividing by $dt$ gives: $$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d\phi}{dt}rdr=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}rdr = \frac{1}{2}\omega r dr$$

Now, I believe, the next step is to integrate from $r$ to $r+dr$?
I think I'm probably complicating something. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290294/2451

Answer (score 2):

It all comes down to evaluating one cross-product, which is best done in the ${\{\hat{r},\hat{\phi},\hat{z}\}}$ basis. 
$$\eqalign{
 r\times (r+dr) &= r\times dr \cr
  &= (\hat{r}\,r)\times (\hat{\phi}\,dr_\phi + \hat{r}\,dr_r) \cr
  &= \hat{z}\,r\,dr_\phi \cr
  &= \hat{z}\,r^2\,d\phi \cr
}$$
Half the magnitude of the cross-product yields the swept area 
$$\eqalign{
 dA &= \frac{1}{2}r^2\,d\phi \cr\cr
 \frac{dA}{dt} &= \frac{1}{2}r^2\,\frac{d\phi}{dt} \cr\cr
}$$
Others have suggested that making the angle really small will make $dr$ nearly perpendicular to $r$, however that is not true.

The key is that $dr$ has components in both the $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\phi}$ directions, but the cross product with $r$ annihilates the $\hat{r}$-component.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you get $dr_\phi = rd\phi$?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I believe when finding |r x (r+dr)| , it simplifies to |r x dr| where we usually take the angle between those to be close enough to a right angle ( looks like you've taken it to be phi) to approximate it to rdr. After substituting that and converting dr  in terms of the angle you should get the desired result.

P.s. sorry for the lack of notation, I'm on my phone.

Comment: How do you convert $d\vec{r}$ in terms of the angle?

Comment: @sequence you could write dr = r*d(phi) ( seeing as it is a infinitesimally small angle you can approximate the radius to be constant) Then all you need to do is divide both sides of the equation by dt and note that d(phi)/dt  = angular velocity omega.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead first express the element of area swept out by a radial vector in Cartesian coordinates $$dA=\|\mathbf r\times(\mathbf r+d\mathbf r)\|=\|\mathbf r\times d\mathbf r\|=\frac12|x\,dy-y\,dx|$$ and then pull back to polar coordinates: $$\begin{align}dA&=\frac12|(\sin\phi\,dr+r\cos\phi\,d\phi)\,r\cos\phi-(\cos\phi\,dr-r\sin\phi\,d\phi)\,r\sin\phi| \\
&=\frac12|(r\cos\phi\sin\phi-r\cos\phi\sin\phi)\,dr+(r^2\cos^2\phi+r^2\sin^2\phi)\,d\phi| \\
&=\frac12|r^2\,d\phi|.\end{align}$$